# VSCode randomly gets SyntaxError when running Python but works after restarting VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So I started with Python in VS Code. I can run my python Files but sometimes it just stopps working and I get this weird Error Message and don't know what it means:

```
& C:/Users/R.Kensy/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe d:/Python/Lists.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Users/R.Kensy/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe d:/Python/Lists.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Even tho there is nothing in Line 1 and I could run the code without a problem one minute ago. When I restart VSCode and dont change the code it just runs the code without an error.

Comment: Judging from the error message, it is warning of a syntax error. Try reinstalling the [python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) or install a [pre-release version](https://imgur.com/a/xKOShpI). Or reinstall [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) after uninstalling.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled everything and deleted all the extensions in VS Code, and it seems to work for now.